# Display the rows from query in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code to get all the data from my products table. It's working great like this:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['id'];
            echo $row['country'];
            echo $row['price'];
            echo $row['games'];
            echo $row['plus'];
            echo $row['buylink'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
```

But I want these results to be shown in a table inside the body. I tried something but it's not working.

This is how the table looks :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Games</th>
    <th>Plus</th>
    <th>Buy Link</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['games']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['plus']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['buylink']; ?></td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened? If the `<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>` is your attempts you need to have that in the `while`.

Comment: The code inside the <tbody> it's not working, not showing anything

Comment: Where is the `while`? How does the first code chunk relate to the second?

Comment: The first code contains the while code..

Comment: So the first code does nothing with the second code? `$row` is undefined in that case.

Comment: Can you show me an examle on how to display the result inside the table?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
?>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Games</th>
      <th>Plus</th>
      <th>Buy Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['games']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['plus']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['buylink']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}else {
 // if there is no result... Code something here.
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont get any errors now, but the table is still empty.. I dont know what may be the problem

Comment: find <?php }?> </tbody> and change <?php } ?> </tbody> and try again pls. Maybe an error bcs of space. This code must work great. There must not be any problem. If you have a problem again please upload your .php file to yandisk and lets look. I think you wrote an unnecessary comma to somewhere in your codes.

Answer (score 0):

LE:
Each html table row is created based on each database's table row. So, you just need to loop through the result set (that `while`), and for each iteration of the loop, you need to create a new html table row:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Games</th>
            <th>Plus</th>
            <th>Buy Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['games']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['plus']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['buylink']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code might provide answer to the question, it is always better to add some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Youre getting close. You need to have the loop spit out the rows into the html.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Games</th>
    <th>Plus</th>
    <th>Buy Link</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td>$item</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}

?>
</tbody>
```

also instead of using a associative array and indexing into it (ie. $row['country']), You can use a normal array and a foreach loop to cut down on the code.

Comment: Tryed that but i get this error : Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_row(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result..

Comment: Above this code in <?php  ?> tags do you have something like this?     $mysql = new mysqli();
$mysql->connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx');


$sql = "SQL GOES HERE";
$result = $mysql->query($sql);

Comment: Yes i do i have the connection in other file db.php and i do require 'db.php' on the top.. As i sayd the first code i posted works! it displays the data but outside the table on top of my site.. i want it to be displayed in the table

$sql = "SELECT id, country, price, games, plus, buylink FROM products";

if ($result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
  {
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // Free result set
  } 
this code works fine

Comment: Did you used the variable name $result twice or reassign it?

Comment: I used it twice

Comment: You put a comment for //free result set. If you free up result before this loop then you will get a error

Comment: I use the mysqli_free_result($result); at the very bottom, i think thats not the problem

Comment: at the top of my site using this code if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['id'];
            echo $row['country'];
            echo $row['price'];
            echo $row['games'];
            echo $row['plus'];
            echo $row['buylink'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        
    }
it works http://prntscr.com/ebbvfu it shows the data..